# Проблема с работой реферальной системы в телеграме

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, peewee

Возникла проблема с базой данных
Пытался сделать реферальную систему, но после перехода по ссылке и нажатия на кнопку start в телеграме, ничего не проиходит, а должно отправится сообщение тому кто отправил ссылку и тому кто перешел по ней, ни тому ни тому не отправляется сообщение
в коде использую peewee и telebot

```
# Обработчик всех текстовых сообщений
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text_message(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    text = message.text
    
    # Проверяем, содержит ли сообщение реферральную ссылку
    if text.startswith(f'https://t.me/{bot_username}?start='):
        referral_code = text.split('=')[1]
        
        # Получаем информацию о реферрере
        referrer = User.select().where(User.referral_link == referral_code).first()
        
        if referrer:
            referrer_id = referrer.user_id
            
            # Начисляем монеты реферреру и пользователю, перешедшему по ссылке
            user, created = User.get_or_create(user_id=user_id)
            user.coins += 5
            user.save()
            referrer.coins += 10
            referrer.referral_count += 1
            referrer.save()
            
            bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Вы получили 5 монет за переход по реферральной ссылке.')
            bot.send_message(referrer_id, 'Вам начислено 10 монет за приглашение нового пользователя.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Обработчик должен быть именно на команду start (На все сообщения ставить такую проверку нет смысла. Ваш код никак не реагировал потому что в message.text нет всей ссылки. Там сохраняется только часть аргументы ссылки т.е. то что следует после символа '?'

Это хорошо видно по строчку кода `message.text[7:]`. Тут мы отсекаем строчку '/start=' (Слэш тут есть потому что это команда)

Вот код который будет работать:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    referral_code = message.text[7:]
    if referral_code:
        # Получаем информацию о реферрере
        referrer = User.select().where(User.referral_link == referral_code).first()
        
        if referrer:
            referrer_id = referrer.user_id
            
            # Начисляем монеты реферреру и пользователю, перешедшему по ссылке
            user, created = User.get_or_create(user_id=user_id)
            user.coins += 5
            user.save()
            referrer.coins += 10
            referrer.referral_count += 1
            referrer.save()
            
            bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Вы получили 5 монет за переход по реферральной ссылке.')
            bot.send_message(referrer_id, 'Вам начислено 10 монет за приглашение нового пользователя.')
```

Comment: Все равно не работает

Comment: есть какая-то ошибка? покажи что находится у тебя в message.text когда пользователь переходит по реф. ссылке

Comment: /start 5640081965
выводится это это

Comment: тогда мне кажется что проблема в том что referral_code это строка, преобразуй ее в число, можно вот так сделать `referral_code = int(message.text[7:])`

Comment: Щас телеграм очнется и я проверю

Comment: все точно также остается, не начисляются коины

Comment: я вывел в консоль все данные в этой функции
по сути должно выводится 3 строки данных но выводится только 2
/start 5640081965 - message.text,
5640081965 - переменная referral_code
должно еще выводится referrer но она не выводится

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то в этой строке  - referrer = User.select().where(User.referral_link == referral_code).first()
должны получатся данные от реферрера но они не получаются

Comment: да, дело точно в этой строке, покажи свою модель пользователя и скажи какую СУБД ты используешься

Comment: бд - sqlite вместе с peewee а вот модель пользователя хз
если я правильно понял то модель пользователя это столбцы которые принадлежат одному из юзеров?

Comment: нужно быть уверенным что peewee вообще работает. создать мини-скрипт который бы проверил твою строку которая достает рефферера